# Faking HDRi Reflections with an orthographic camera

Tags: materials, shaders, lighting, orthographic

Is it possible to fake perspective reflections of a HRDi in a scene with an orthographic camera?

As reflection rays are parallel on flat surfaces, every face of a glossy object has a uniform color instead of color variations from the HDRi.

I'd prefer a node-only setup to baking textures.
Setting the camera back to perspective and using a high focal length is Plan B.

Comment: Reflections work fine with orthographic cameras, at least on non planar geometry

Comment: obviously, as rays from non planar faces won't be parallel. edited my answer to target falt faces specifically.