# How to get angle chrome in orthographic view EEVEE?

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor

Months ago I asked how to make angled chrome texture: [How to create a chrome texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/168180/31447) Since I use EEVEE, I'm using the option [@Robbin Betts recommend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168190/31447). Remaining issue is that in **orthographic view** that typical chrome-like angled look disappears.

So I tried to slightly tilt the X axis to get proper reflection (on my text) but if I use the image texture in orthographic view its more visible. During the animation when it rotates it looks kinda fake:

[image]

**Q:** Is there a way to improve the chrome nodes, or animation to give it a more realistic appearance? I also have a Blender file to share the animation if someone wants to have a look at it.

Comment: Please ask a specific question in the title and add any specific goal to your question -> Makes it useful to others (searching for the same subject in the future) too. Short reminder: This is no regular forum, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the link to your previous question otherwise your question is incomprehensible to others. However, the second paragrpah: "*(on my text) but if I use the image texture in orthographic view its more visible. During the animation when it rotates it looks kinda fake...*" is still a mess. What text are you talking about? What animation are you talking about?

Comment: Here's a brief animation: https://streamable.com/leb261

Comment: Hello :). Environment reflections are very limited in orthographic view (they're basically just one color) which does look a bit fake (orthographic view itself also can't be achieved with a real camera).

Comment: Ok Jachym, thanks for the information!Kind regards.

Comment: @JachymMichal has nailed the reason.. I wonder if there's a get-around?

Comment: Related: [Faking HDRi Reflections with an orthographic camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/110131/78972)

Comment: Related: [Chrome Reflections On Flat Surfaces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/168762/78972)

Comment: Here are 2 examples, one is using the texture and the other one is using Node for angel chrome material @robinBetts had shown a while ago. But the image texture shows in orthographic view, so it has to do with the difference of using images vs nodes. https://ibb.co/LpPst5J

Comment: Just checking.. the object Z-axis runs flat-to flat?

Comment: Yes, its Z axis. I took your Node set up from a previous post: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168180/how-to-create-a-chrome-texture